# Adding Facebook banner Ad in Android

Tags: android, facebook-ads-api

I've added a Facebook banner ad in my Android app . I used a valid banner ID but there is nothing . I want to know if my code has something wrong .

Here is my code

in `build.app`

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.18.0'
```

in `MainActivity`

```
com.facebook.ads.AdView adView2 = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this, "my_banner_id",AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
    LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
    adContainer.addView(adView2);
    adView2.loadAd();
```

in activity_main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    />
```

Comment: check your logcat for possible reason.

Comment: are you testing it on emulator or real device?

Comment: On real device .

Comment: your code is perfect try to see some debug message in logcat.

Comment: I found this in  logcat 
` When testing your app with Facebook's ad units you must specify the device hashed ID to ensure the delivery of test ads, add the following code before loading an ad: AdSettings.addTestDevice("some letteres");`
And I will try this line .

Comment: @NoumanCh when I added the above line , I had this exception 
`MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController$c@421c8bd8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I change:

`app.build`

from

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.18.0'
```

to

```
 compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.23.0'
```

In `MainActivity`

from

```
com.facebook.ads.AdView adView2 = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this, "my_banner_id",AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
```

to

```
Resources res = getResources();
    com.facebook.ads.AdView adView2 = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this,res.getString(R.string.facebook_banner),AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
```

But I still have this error in `Logs`

```
TeamDetails has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController$c@3012f931 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

I don't know why this error still appears in `Logs` .

Comment: try adding @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.destroy();
  }
  super.onDestroy();
}

Comment: @DivyeshPatel What will happen when I add the `onDestroy()` function ?

Comment: it properly close adview when activity/fragment destorys

Comment: Thank you , but is there a function like destroy in `adView`  for `InterstitialAd` ?

Comment: ondestory function is available in activity or fragment

Comment: I mean `adView.destroy()` .

Answer (score 1):

Take a step by step approach with the facebook ads sdk. Make sure you use the latest version, as old version will not receive ads. I was running an older version and ads stopped rendering.

[FAN Android Integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android)

In order to receive ads, you must have a facebook account on the test device, that is linked to the monetisation manager property you are trying to monetise.

Here is how I render a FAN banner. keep in mind, I have a rendering method which receives `adConfig` as a configuration object which contains the facebook adUnit and a `parent` object, which is the layout container where I want to render the add (these are specific to my project only):

```
    if (adConfig != null && adConfig.getAdUnit() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "displayBanner " + adConfig.getClass().getSimpleName() + " : " + adConfig.getAdUnit());
        parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        parent.removeAllViews();
        com.facebook.ads.AdView adView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(parent.getContext(), adConfig.getAdUnit(), com.facebook.ads.AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
        parent.addView(adView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adView.loadAd();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , my problem was using an old version of the Facebook ads sdk .

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve this issue:

- Add this testing id to your onCreate method.

  `AdSettings.addTestDevice("you hash id");`
- Sometime due to incomplete payroll we have to face problem. Cross check your payroll information is complete.

For more details on this issue check this link. [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#faq_1204719862895859)

Comment: Thank you for your answer . What is the hash id ?

Comment: you can create testing hash id from facebook developers console from where you have created the banner ads.

Comment: this link will be helpful for you. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing

Comment: Ok when I used a hash_id , the add doesn't appear and gives me this error `has leaked IntentReceiver com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController$c@421bdf40 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()? `

Comment: nothing useful found for you https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1816502901941129/.

Comment: Thank you I will check it and tell you the result .

Comment: I see your comment in this link .. Thank you very much for helping me . I hope they answer you because they didn't write the answer

Comment: my pleasure buddy hope we will get this issue resolved.

Comment: Hello Nouman :) see my edit in the question I think I have solved it .

Comment: that really sounds great please add your solution as an answer to your question. it will be help ful for others.

Comment: Thank you , I posted it  :)